# Converting CasMate Pro files to a vector format, workaround

Tags: print-design

[image]

I have a number of vectorial files that were created eons ago with a software called CasMate Pro(above) for the purpose of cutting those vectors with vinyl cutters.

I googled a bit and I found out that the above software is not produced anymore and that there are some alternatives/workarounds...

**My question:

Is there someone else around here with this problem?

**What was your workaround to import those files and work with them in a more recent software?**

Comment: If you take a look at the source code of one of the files (open it up in a text editor), is it readable? A lot of vector file formats are just some form of XML, perhaps the points could be extracted and converted to a modern format

Comment: Flexi actually (through numerous acquisitions) ended up acquiring CASmate. Believe me, I know the pain here as Im upgrading a companies hardware from Windows 98!

Answer (score 2):

From [this question in SU](https://superuser.com/questions/157726/convert-scv-to-eps) rearding `.SCV` files (not sure if it's the same program or same family, hope it helps).

> A vector program called [i-DesignR](http://www.graphtecamerica.com/software.html) by Graphtec has Casmate SCV on
>   their [import list (PDF)](http://www.graphtecamerica.com/datasheets/i-DesignR_Import-Export_File_Types.pdf). I think I read somewhere on this site
>   that the [Flexi Family](http://www.saintl.biz/Flexi8482;_FAMILY28.asp) software can do it.

The OP mentions [Flexi](http://www.thinksai.com/british-flexi3) worked for him:

"*Flexi sets a new industry standard with robust features that maximise production. Flexi excels as a one-stop software solution with a wealth of industry-specific design tools, easy-to-use interface and thousands of drivers to run your cutters, printers and hybrids. Flexi... the leading software for sign making!*"

Comment: The problem with Flexi and i-DesignR both(i think) is that you cannot get a demo version available for download to see if it does the job or not, and I am sure that in some cases it doesn't do it.

Comment: Are your files .SCV? Also, I'm sure you can write to these guys and tell them about your situation. They should be able to answer at least some of your main questions.

Answer (score 1):

export scv file from casmate as dxf or ps (lower option) to corel draw...its working with no problem....

Answer (score 1):

An easy to use vector cutting program called Easy Cut Studio from http://www.easycutstudio.com/ is work fine for converting CasMate Pro files to a vector format.

Comment: Hi TonyDu, your answer looks very much like spam. Care to add more information about it?

Answer (score 0):

Casmate File is already  vector.
FlexiSign opens Casmate files and can use Casfonts too.